# Raspberry Pi QDBus error: could not send message to service

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, qt5, raspbian, qdbus

i am trying to execute a simple qt5 c++ program to get all wifi networks listed, when i execute it in linux mint it works out of the box, but when i try to execute it in Raspberry pi (latest raspbian) i get the following error:

```
QDBusConnection: error: could not send message to service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" path "" interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member "Introspect":
ERROR : Interface invalid
```

My wifi dongle is working because i can list all wifi networks with this command:
 `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

What is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ups, networkmanager was not installed in Raspberry Pi: sudo apt-get install network-manager